# Compare trees in Scala

Tags: scala, tree, stream, iterator

Suppose I need to compare tree-like data structures (e.g. file system directories or XML documents) in Scala. It is easy if I *flatten* trees to create sequences but it looks a waste of memory. So, I would like to flatten the trees to create iterators/streams. Does it make sense ? What would you suggest: iterator or stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about memory consumption, you should avoid streams. They will end up allocating as much memory as there are nodes that you are traversing. Using a stream is similar to flattening to a sequence, only it's done lazily.

It might be better to use an iterator. However, tree iterators can be tricky to implement. An easier, and probably more efficient solution, is to simply use recursion on both trees you want to compare. E.g.:

```
def compare(a: Tree, b: Tree): Boolean = {
  if (/* trees a and be are not equal */) false
  else if (a.children.length != b.children.length) false
  else {
    for ((c1, c2) <- a.children zip b.children) {
      if (!compare(c1, c2)) return false
    }
    true
  }
}
```

If you're worried about performance, you might want to get rid of the for-comprehension above, and use a while loop to iterate through the child nodes.

Comment: Thank you. What if trees are very large and the recursion is not feasible. Should I implement a tree iterator ?

Comment: If trees are so large that the recursion is not feasible because of stack overflows, then you could use iterators, or you cold use a pair of `Stack`s to push and pop nodes of the two trees and compare them.